# listviewcontroller leaving room for two tabbars at the bottom when loading the VC programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, listview, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

When I load the scene through just normal segues, the tabbar is at the bottom and its nice and clean. However when I come back to it via code, loading the Tabbarcontroller, then the nav bar then my custom VC. It loads perfect but theres X amount of pixels for the tabbar, but an additional X amount of pixels all blank between the custom VC and the tab bar. Essentially counting for two tab bars.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "searchSegue") {
        let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
        let navController = nav.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
        let listController = navController.topViewController as! RecipeListViewController
        listController.ingredientSearch = (self.ingredIDs as String);

    }
}
```

[messed up list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNg0p.jpg)

Comment: @AlejandroIván added

Comment: @AlejandroIván is that better? its via a button and push segue

Comment: @AlejandroIván added picture of error happening

Comment: [here are the contraints](http://imgur.com/1BXT2Qq) It's just a list view controller

Comment: @AlejandroIván I added an image of it being messed up